# A CNN in Python WITHOUT frameworks

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x, machine-learning, neural-network

Here's some code that I've written for implementing a Convolutional Neural Network for recognising handwritten digits from the MNIST dataset over the last two days (after a lot of research into figuring out how to convert mathematical equations into code).

```
""" Convolutional Neural Network """


import numpy as np
import sklearn.datasets
import random
import math
from skimage.measure import block_reduce
from scipy.signal import convolve
import time

def reLU(z):           # activation function
    return z * (z > 0)

""" ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- """

class ConvPoolLayer:     
    def __init__(self, in_dim, filter_dim, pool_dim=None, conv_stride=1):
        self.in_dim = in_dim
        self.out_dim =      (filter_dim[0], int(round(((0.0 + in_dim[-2] - filter_dim[-2]) / conv_stride + 1) / pool_dim[-2])),  \
                    int(round(((0.0 + in_dim[-1] - filter_dim[-1]) / conv_stride + 1) / pool_dim[-1]))) \
                if pool_dim \
                else \
                    (num_filters, ((in_dim[-2] - filter_dim[-2]) / conv_stride + 1), \
                            ((in_dim[-1] - filter_dim[-1]) / conv_stride + 1) )

        self.filter_dim = filter_dim
        self.pool_dim = pool_dim

        self.W = np.random.randn(*filter_dim) * np.sqrt(2.0 / (sum(filter_dim))).astype(np.float32)
        self.B = np.zeros(((in_dim[-1] - filter_dim[-1]) / conv_stride + 1, 1)).astype(np.float32)

    def feedforward(self, x, W, b, step):
        self.x = x.reshape(step, self.in_dim[-2], self.in_dim[-1])
        activation = reLU(np.array([convolve(self.x, w, mode='valid') for w in W]) + b.reshape(1, -1, 1))

        if self.pool_dim: 
            return block_reduce(activation, block_size=tuple([1] + list(self.pool_dim)), func=np.max)
        else: 
            return activation

    def backpropagate(self, delta, W, index):
        delta = delta.reshape(len(W), 1, int((np.prod(delta.shape) // len(W)) ** 0.5), -1)
        if self.pool_dim: 
            delta = delta.repeat(self.pool_dim[-2], axis=2).repeat(self.pool_dim[-1], axis=3)   # may have to change this for maxpooling
        dw = np.array([np.rot90(convolve(self.x[index].reshape(1, self.in_dim[-2], self.in_dim[-1]), np.rot90(d, 2), mode='valid'), 2) for d in delta])
        db = np.sum(np.array([np.sum(d, axis=(1, )).reshape(-1, 1) for d in delta]), axis=0)

        return None, dw, db


class FullyConnectedLayer:
    def __init__(self, in_size, out_size):
        self.in_size = in_size
        self.out_size = out_size

        self.W = np.random.randn(out_size, in_size) * np.sqrt(2.0 / (in_size + out_size)).astype(np.float32)
        self.B = np.zeros((out_size, 1)).astype(np.float32)

    def feedforward(self, x, w, b, step):
        self.x = x.reshape(step, -1)
        activation = reLU(np.dot(w, self.x.T) + b).T
        return activation

    def backpropagate(self, delta, w, index):
        dw = np.multiply(delta, self.x[index])
        db = delta
        delta = np.dot(w.T, delta) * (self.x[index].reshape(-1, 1) > 0)

        return delta, dw, db


class SoftmaxLayer:
    def __init__(self, in_size, out_size):
        self.in_size = in_size
        self.out_size = out_size

        self.W = np.random.randn(out_size, in_size) * np.sqrt(2.0 / (in_size + out_size)).astype(np.float32)
        self.B = np.zeros((out_size, 1)).astype(np.float32)

    def feedforward(self, x, w, b, step):
        self.x = x.reshape(step, -1)
        return reLU(np.dot(w, self.x.T) + b).T

    def backpropagate(self, t, y, w, index):
        t = np.exp(t)
        t /= np.sum(t)
        delta = (t - y) * (t > 0)

        dw = np.multiply(delta, self.x[index])
        db = delta
        delta = np.dot(w.T, delta) * (self.x[index].reshape(-1, 1) > 0)

        return delta, dw, db

""" ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- """

class ConvolutionalNeuralNet:
    def __init__(self, layers, learning_rate=0.01, reg_lambda=0.05):
        self.layers = []
        self.W = []
        self.B = []

        for l in layers:
            if l['type'].lower() == 'conv':
                self.layers.append(ConvPoolLayer(**l['args']))
            elif l['type'].lower() == 'fc':
                self.layers.append(FullyConnectedLayer(**l['args']))
            else:
                self.layers.append(SoftmaxLayer(**l['args']))

            self.layers[-1].layer_type = l['type'] 
            self.W.append(self.layers[-1].W)
            self.B.append(self.layers[-1].B)

        self.W = np.array(self.W)
        self.B = np.array(self.B)
        self.num_layers = len(layers)
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.reg_lambda = reg_lambda

    def __feedforward(self, x):
        for i in range(len(self.layers)):
            x = self.layers[i].feedforward(x, self.W[i], self.B[i], step=1)
        return x

    def __backpropagation(self, inputs, targets, is_val=False):
        # forward pass
        step = len(inputs)
        for i in range(len(self.layers)):
            inputs = self.layers[i].feedforward(inputs, self.W[i], self.B[i], step)

        # backward pass
        weight_gradients = np.array([np.zeros(w.shape) for w in self.W])
        bias_gradients = np.array([np.zeros(b.shape) for b in self.B])

        for i in range(len(targets)):
            delta, dw, db = self.layers[-1].backpropagate(inputs[i].reshape(-1, 1), targets[i], self.W[-1], index=i)
            weight_gradients[-1] += dw
            bias_gradients[-1] += db

            for j in xrange(2, self.num_layers + 1):
                delta, dw, db = self.layers[-j].backpropagate(delta, self.W[-j], index=i)
                weight_gradients[-j] += dw
                bias_gradients[-j] += db

        if is_val:
            weight_gradients += self.reg_lambda * weight_gradients

        self.W += -self.learning_rate * weight_gradients
        self.B += -self.learning_rate * bias_gradients

    def train(self, training_data, validation_data, epochs=10):
        acc = 0

        step, val_step = 25, 25

        inputs = [data[0] for data in training_data]
        targets = [data[1] for data in training_data]

        val_inputs = [x[0] for x in validation_data]
        val_targets = [x[1] for x in validation_data]

        for i in xrange(epochs):
            for j in xrange(0, len(inputs), step):
                self.__backpropagation(np.array(inputs[j : j + step]), targets[j : j + step])

            if validation_data:
                for j in xrange(0, len(val_inputs), val_step):
                    self.__backpropagation(np.array(val_inputs[j : j + val_step]), val_targets[j : j + val_step], is_val=True)

            print("{} epoch(s) done".format(i + 1))

            # new_acc = CN.test(test_data)          
            # acc = new_acc
            # print "Accuracy:", str(acc) + "%"

            self.learning_rate -= self.learning_rate * 0.35

        print("Training done.")

    def test(self, test_data):
        test_results = [(np.argmax(self.__feedforward(x[0])), np.argmax(x[1])) for x in test_data]
        return float(sum([int(x == y) for (x, y) in test_results])) / len(test_data) * 100

    def dump(self, file):
        pickle.dump(self, open(file, "wb"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    global test_data

    def transform_target(y):
        t = np.zeros((10, 1))
        t[int(y)] = 1.0
        return t

    total = 5000
    training = int(total * 0.70)
    val = int(total * 0.15)
    test = int(total * 0.15)

    mnist = sklearn.datasets.fetch_mldata('MNIST original', data_home='./data')

    data = list(zip(mnist.data, mnist.target))
    random.shuffle(data)
    data = data[:total]
    data = [(x[0].astype(bool).astype(int).reshape(-1,), transform_target(x[1])) for x in data]

    train_data = data[:training]
    val_data = data[training:training + val]
    test_data = data[training + val:]

    print "Data fetched"

    CN = ConvolutionalNeuralNet(layers=[{   'type': 'conv', 
                                    'args': 
                                        {   'in_dim'        : (1, 28, 28),  
                                            'filter_dim'    : (1, 1, 3, 3),     # number of filters, (z, x, y) dims
                                            'pool_dim'      : (1, 2, 2), 
                                        },
                                },

                                {   'type': 'fc', 
                                    'args': 
                                        {
                                            'in_size'       : 1 * 169, 
                                            'out_size'      : 50, 
                                        } 
                                },

                                {   'type': 'softmax', 
                                    'args': 
                                        {
                                            'in_size'       : 50, 
                                            'out_size'      : 10, 
                                        } 
                                }, ],  learning_rate=0.01, reg_lambda=0.05)

    s = time.time()
    CN.train(train_data, val_data, epochs=3)
    e = time.time()

    print "Network trained"

    print "Accuracy:", str(CN.test(test_data)) + "%"
    print "Time taken: ", (e - s)
```

I have not used Theano or any other frameworks. My goal is:

1. Optimise the feedforward and back-propagation functions for all
   layers
2. Make the network robust under all training conditions (not sure if it is yet)
3. Replace the existing scipy.signal.convolve and skimage.measure.block_reduce with implementations that are faster,
   if possible.
4. Replace mean pooling with max pooling (I've kept mean pooling for now since it is easier to back-propagate).

I have also assumed, for the sake of simplicity, that:

1. The first layer is always a convolutional layer
2. There is only one convolutional layer in the network

Previously, I had made it possible to include more convolutional layers, but I was not sure whether I was back-propagating properly between convolutional layers, plus it was more generic so it ran slower.

Comments and suggestions welcome.

Comment: It is a great code for a start. I did test it and works great. However, I tried to add more than 1 CONV filter without luck. I did it by putting "'filter_dim'    : (2, 1, 3, 3)" and "'in_size'       : 2 * 169". Is this correct? Actually, it looks like working but instead 80+% I get around 15% accuracy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Disclaimer:*** I know practically nothing about ML or neural networks.

The big problem with this program is readability. There are no docstrings or comments, so even somebody who knows about ML would have difficulty using this. for example, what arguments should I pass to the `ConvPoolLayer` constructor? What does `reLU(z)` represent? And so on.

Particularly when the code is in a specialist area, it’s essential to have comments explaining *why* the code was written this way – what’s it trying to do, what concepts does the code map to.
This will make it much easier for other people to follow – including you, in six months time!

---

And some more specific observations:

- **Run a PEP 8 linter.**  There’s a bunch of little [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) violations – line length, whitespace, and so on – a linting tool like `flake8` can help you spot those. Makes your code look more like other Python, and so easier for others to read.
- **Use new-style classes.** If you’re using Python 2, your classes should all subclass from `object`.  This comes with a bunch of minor benefits and is generally good practice. See the [Python Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass) for more background.
- **Don’t skimp on variable names.**  Lots of your code uses one or two-letter variable names.  That hurts readability, and can make it harder to search for a variable’s use in code. Longer, more expressive names are almost always better – use them!
- **Use collections.namedtuple for multi-part arguments.**  I’m guessing based on [this ML tutorial](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lenet.html#putting-it-all-together) that the arguments for `ConvPoolLayer` are multi-part. For example, the `filter_dim` argument should have four components:

  - number of filters
  - number of input feature maps
  - filter height
  - filter width

  Right now, you’re accessing those components by numerical index, which isn’t great for readability. If you created a [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html?highlight=collections.namedtuple#collections.namedtuple) to represent a filter shape, you’d be able to look up those properties by name. For example:

  ```
  from collections import namedtuple

  FilterDim = namedtuple('filterdim',
                         ['num_filters', 'num_maps', 'height', 'width'])

  foo = FilterDim(5, 5, 10, 3)
  foo.num_maps  # 5
  ```

  This would significantly improve the readability of your code.
- **The `__init__` method of ConvPoolLayer.**

  - It uses a `num_filters` variable that doesn't seem to be defined anywhere.
  - I’m not a big fan of the `foo = bar if condition else baz` ternary operator in Python, and in this case it should definitely be split over multiple lines. I’d also suggest breaking the components of the tuple over multiple lines, to make it easier to see where one ends and the next begins. For example:

    ```
    if pool_dim:
        self.out_dim = (
            filter_dim[0],
            int(round(((0.0 + in_dim[-2] - filter_dim[-2]) / conv_stride + 1) / pool_dim[-2])),
            int(round(((0.0 + in_dim[-1] - filter_dim[-1]) / conv_stride + 1) / pool_dim[-1]))
        )
    else:
        self.out_dim = (
            num_filters,
            (in_dim[-2] - filter_dim[-2]) / conv_stride + 1,
            (in_dim[-1] - filter_dim[-1]) / conv_stride + 1
        )
    ```

    This makes it easier to read, and easier to see the similarities between different arguments.  And as above, you should probably consider defining a named tuple for this stuff.
- **Make use of enumerate.**  When you need to loop over both the index and element of a list, using `enumerate()` is cleaner than doing one or the other. For example, this snippet:

  ```
  for i in range(len(targets)):
      delta, dw, db = self.layers[-1].backpropagate(
          inputs[i].reshape(-1, 1),
          targets[i],
          self.W[-1],
          index=i)
  ```

  can become slightly neater:

  ```
  for idx, target in enumerate(targets):
      delta, dw, db = self.layers[-1].backpropagate(
          inputs[idx].reshape(-1, 1),
          target,
          self.W[-1],
          index=idx)
  ```
- **As well as `+=`, you have `-=`.** Replace:

  ```
  self.W += -self.learning_rate * weight_gradients
  ```

  with

  ```
  self.W -= self.learning_rate * weight_gradients
  ```

Comment: Thanks! In my pursuit of trying to make the operation of CNNs more transparent (by not using frameworks), I indeed ended up making it just as obscure, if not worse. Thanks for taking the time to write a long meaningful post. I like the fact that you even did research, knowing nothing on the subject. 
Thanks!